# sort the rows of the matrix in ascending lexicographic order

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Hi I need help with one of my homework tasks. I need to improve the speed of the code that I have, please help me?
[image]

That is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    int table[n][m];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cin>>table[i][j];
        }
    }

    bool isSorted = false;

    while (!isSorted) {
        isSorted = true;

        for(int i=0;i<n - 1;i++)
        {
            std::string str = "";
            std::string str2 = "";
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                str += table[i][j] + '0';
                str2 += table[i+1][j] + '0';
            }

            // cout << str2 << " < " << str << " Bool " << (str2 > str) << endl;

            if (str2 < str) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    int t = table[i][k];
                    table[i][k] = table[i + 1][k];
                    table[i + 1][k] = t;
                }
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        cout<<table[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Task is:
A matrix with M lines and N ladder is given. To sort the rows of the matrix in ascending lexicographic order, ie if A = A (1), A (2), ..., A (n) and B = B (1), B (2) ..., B (n) are two lines of the matrix, such that A (1) = B (1), A (2) = B (2) and A (k + 1)  B (k + 1) the sorted matrix.

Input format

Each of the following keys should be listed in the table below.

```
Constraints

3<M<1024, 3<N<1024
```

Output format

You have to calculate the matrix.

```
Sample Input

4 4
6 1 1 2
7 2 9 4
7 3 1 5
7 2 9 3

Sample Output

6 1 1 2
7 2 9 3
7 2 9 4
7 3 1 5
```

Comment: Fyi, I don't know what C++ tutorial you're using that suggests `int table[n][m];`, but it's not standard compliant (VLAs are not part of C++). A vector of vectors would make this task trivial

Comment: @WhozCraig - It works in C, as g++ supports it as an extension, but I'm sure you already knew that. :)

Comment: Wrong Answer means wrong answer, not too slow...

Comment: *I need to improve the speed of the code that I have, please help me?* -- If `n` and `m` are large, you have potential to blow out the stack using the non-standard VLA's.  Even if you made it past that, you coded (it seems to be) one of the worst sorting algorithms to choose -- bubble sort.

Comment: Александър  - why are you converting your matrix of integers back to strings and then comparing strings?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::sort`?

Comment: I am not typing C++ for the last 5 years. I am a FrontEnd-er and I need to finish several tasks. I have only one 1 exam remain. I will never type on C++ again. I just need to finish the exam. Please guys help me. I am struggaling for the last 2 days with all those tasks. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can someone help me in private for several small tasks? I will pay You if need. Please help me!?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to support you and show you one of the many possible solutions.

Your program has still many C-style elements, like plain arrays or scanf. 
I would like to switch over to modern C++.

The usage of the STL and of algorithms is highly recomended.

And, nowadays people will always use STL containers like std::vector of std::vector to implement the concept of a matrix.

I will embed everything in a class.

Reading and writing values will be done with the iostream library. And for user defined types the extractor and inserter operator (>> and <<) will be overwritten. With that, an easy usage of the existing io facilities is possible.

Algorithms can be used to work on parts of or a complete container. And element wise operations for container elements will be done using iterators. As you will see, we "copy" the values from the input to the matrix and back to the output.

So, in the below listing, you will see the main tasks beeing done in 3 lines of code.

Please also note: The sorting is very fast. And it works, because the less-than-operator (<) is also present for std::vectors

Please see:

EDIT: Code updated as per L.F.'s comment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


// Constraints for number of rows and columns
constexpr int ConstraintMin = 3;
constexpr int ConstraintMax = 1024;
// Custom Class to hold a matrix
class Matrix
{
public:
    // Explicit constructor. Make a matrix with the requested numbers of rows and columns
    explicit Matrix(const size_t numberOrRows, const size_t numberOfColumns) { matrix.resize(numberOrRows); std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [numberOfColumns](Columns & c) { c.resize(numberOfColumns); });     }
    // Main Function of Matrix: Sort.  
    void sort() { std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end()); }

    // Overload extratcor.  Read all data for Matrix from an istream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Matrix& m) {
        std::for_each(m.matrix.begin(), m.matrix.end(), [&is](Columns& columns) {std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(is), columns.size(), columns.begin()); });
        return is;
    }
    // Overload inserter. Write Matrix to ostream
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Matrix& m) {
        std::for_each(m.matrix.begin(), m.matrix.end(), [&os](const Columns & columns) {std::copy_n(columns.begin(), columns.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });
        return os;
    }
protected:
    // The columns in one row of the matrix
    using Columns = std::vector<int>;
    // The container for the data. A vector of columns
    std::vector<Columns> matrix{};
};

int main()
{
    // This will hold the number of rows and columns of our matrix
    int rows{ 0 }, columns{ 0 };

    std::cout << "\nMatrix Sort\n\nEnter the number of rows and columns of the matrix:\n";

    // Read number of rows and columns from user
    std::cin >> rows >> columns;
    // Keep values in limit constraints
    rows = std::min(std::max(ConstraintMin, rows), ConstraintMax);
    columns = std::min(std::max(ConstraintMin, columns), ConstraintMax);

    // Define the matrix with the given numbers of rows and columns
    Matrix matrix(rows, columns);

    std::cout << "\nPlease enter " << rows << " rows and " << columns << " columns:\n";

    // Read the complete matrix
    std::cin >> matrix;
    // Sort it
    matrix.sort();
    // And show the result
    std::cout << "\n\nResult. Sorted matrix:\n" << matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope, I could give you a small impression of the power of modern C++ . . .

Comment: No!  Please, don't overload in the `std` namespace!  That's undefined behavior!

Comment: @L.F.  You are right. I apologize. C++  Lookup rules . . .      I will post a new code.

Comment: @David. Yes, Compiled, debugged and tested with MSVC19. But it was 1 am. I was too tired to test with gcc and clang. I will post an update and test this with gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic . . .

Comment: Maybe I am using all compiler. All tasks are in HackRank.com. And I am using Dev-c++. I can`t compile the code.

Can someone help me in private for several small tasks? I will pay You if need. Please help me!?

Comment: I compiled and tested the code with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (free community edition) and with gcc on a rasperry PI. Configured for C++ 17.  All warnings enabled. No problem at all. I and other people will help you here, without any payment. What's the problem? Please describe.

Comment: Now that's more like it. The first code using `for_each_n` with `>>` and `<<` overload failed to compile with `c++17` or `c++2a`. The original failed to compile with, e.g. `"error: no matching function for call to ‘for_each_n(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type, std::operator>>(std::istream&, Matrix&)::<lambda(Columns&)>)’"`. The current version is fine with `c++11`.